# FullCalendar fetching events from url with jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

after a while playing around with the Full Calendar - http://fullcalendar.io and finishing my REST service that generate a json page containing the following data

> {"product":[{"email":"blablabla@gmail.com","enddate":"Tue May 03
>   2016 16:30:00","id":"33","name":"bla
>   bla","phone":"053-5330826","service":"manhaircut","startdate":"Tue
>   May 03 2016 16:00:00"},{"email":"email@fdjk.com","enddate":"Mon May 02
>   2016 20:00:00","id":"34","name":"fdjk
>   two","phone":"055343582","service":"womanhaircut","startdate":"Mon May
>   02 2016 19:00:00"}]}

I would like to iterate over this page using jQuery and inserting it into my events.

all I have for now in code is :

```
var JSONService = "/CRUDAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        url: JSONService
    })
    .done(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                    resultObject = response.GetDataResult;
                    for (i = 0; i < resultObject.length; i++) {
                        console.log(resultObject[i].lastname);
                    }
                })
            })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) { alert("error" + textStatus); })
    .always(function () { alert("complete"); });
```

which gives me back this in the console :

> Object { product: Array[2] }
>   TypeError: resultObject is undefined

Comment: var resultObject = response.GetDataResult;  You are missing var before resultObject

Comment: doesnt seem to work sadly

Answer (score 0):

managed to solve this problem after reading the entire doc by jquery for iteration and .ajax.

reworked code :

```
var JSONService = "url";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        url: JSONService
    })
    .done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                    $.each(data.product, function(i, product) {
                        console.log(data.product[i].name)
                    });
                })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) { alert("error" + textStatus); })
    .always(function () { alert("complete"); });

});
```